# C# Windows: How can I get more accurate point data from stylus?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, surface

I can only get integer values from wpf e.GetPosition.
How can I get sub-pixel(raw) (or more accurate) data from stylus?

```cs
private void Grid_StylusInAirMove(object sender, StylusEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.GetPosition(Grid1);
    Block1.Text = $ "X {position.X:F2} Y {position.Y:F2}";
}
```

It only shows "X xxx.0 Y xxx.0"
I want more accurate point data

Comment: Why are you marking a question about C# and WPF with the C++ tag?

Comment: I think windows development is close to C++....

Comment: "I want more accurate point data" - sure, but you won't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(Grid1)